# On clicking the textbox the selectRow checkbox function should not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

. .I need a help. . I have a table row in which there is a checkbox, textbox. and some numbers

On clicking the row the checkbox gets checked and clicking it again the checkbox gets unchecked. But there is a problem, after checkbox is checked when i click on textbox to enter a value the checkbox also gets unchecked.I don't want that to to happen. I need to remove the row select function only for the textbox cell. . please help out guys. . .

js code:

```
function selectRow(row)
{
 var chk = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
if (!chk.disabled) {
chk.checked = !chk.checked;
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Js4w7/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add onclick="event.stopPropagation()" to the textbox :

```
<td width="30" valign="middle"><input name="Item2_quantity1" type="text"
class="tb5"placeholder="1" id="Item2_quantity1" size="1" maxlength="2" value="1"
onclick="event.stopPropagation()" /></td>
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/FgZ6v/1/)

Comment: its working. . .but i have a set of 50 text box, So its better to have jquery code

Comment: Then try to add this to the click event of the class they share, if they share any.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using jQuery in fiddle. Try this:

```
$("table#Item2_listing tr").click(function(e){
    if(e.target.type!=="text"){
        var chk = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]')[0];
if (!chk.disabled) {
chk.checked = !chk.checked;
    }
    } 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Js4w7/3/)**

Comment: i have a 50 text-box so how can i have the same function in all boxes